# how Math.random() works for distribution of data?

Tags: java

I am using Math.random() in my code to distribute data into separate bucket.
I want to know if i use Math.random() in multiple places, will it use different number generator or same , as its an static method.

Code example:

```
public void assignVariant1() {
    int c1 = 0 , c2=0 , c3=0 ,c4=0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 100000 ; i++)
    {
        if(Math.random() > 0.5)
        {
            c1++;
        }else
        {
            c2++;
        }

        if(Math.random() > 0.5)
        {
            c3++;
        }else
        {
            c4++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("c1 + c2 "+ (c1+c2));
    System.out.println("c1 + c2 "+ (c3+c4));
}
```

In code above , will it use same pseudorandom-number generator for both Math.random() calls?

Comment: RTFM would be a correct answer here. It would have been faster to read it than to create the question.

Comment: @GhostCat i read the documentation , i got confused with the output i am getting. I was getting sum of (c1+c2) = 100000 and same for (c3+c4), may be that's a coincidence.  Sorry for silly question but does it mean Math.random() will create one set for entire application scope ? and if i am using it to split data in 5 separate places it will give me incorrect probability ?

Comment: No. Think about it: you loop N times. In each loop, you either increase C1 OR C2. In the end, you sum up C1 + C2. Dont you think that the result **must** be N ... just do it manually with a pen and piece of paper. The sum will always be N, but most likely, C1 and C2 will have slightly different values each time!

Comment: ok,  if i change my code to use Math.random() in nested if structure. Then it will show proper behaviour. right ? Here my data set is anyways double.        is there a way to make them independent sets , (or i can look into that direction)?

Answer (score 2):

The **real** answer here is: read the documentation.

The javadoc for [Math.random()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()) is really explicit about this:

> When this method is first called, it creates a single new pseudorandom-number generator, exactly as if by the expression
>
> new java.util.Random()
>
> This new pseudorandom-number generator is used thereafter for all calls to this method and is used nowhere else.

So the take-away: if you have questions about library classes, read the documentation coming with those classes. On a meta level: strive to "answer" such questions yourself; asking other people for explanations might look like a quick detour; but it actually *slows* you down.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the same generator is used. The first time `Math.random()` is called, an instance of the generator is created (internally `new java.util.Random()` is called) and a drawing returned. On subsequent calls, that instance is used to generate the next number.

A small point, you should use `>= 0.5`. This is because the drawing includes 0.0 but not 1.0, and 0.5 is representable exactly as a java `double`. Your current way introduces a statistical bias of `c2` in favour of `c1`, but probably no worse than the generator itself.

Answer (score 1):

> will it use same pseudorandom-number generator for both Math.random() calls?

It will; but if you want to make that explicit, pass it as a parameter to the method:

```
public void assignVariant1(Random r) {
  // ...
  if (r.nextDouble() > 0.5) {
    // ...
  }
  if (r.nextDouble() > 0.5) {
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

This is quite unambiguously using the same `Random` instance each time.

But the real advantage is that it allows you to test the method repeatably, by passing in a `Random` instance with a known seed.

Comment: nice answer, but please nick my note on statistical bias.

Comment: @Bathsheba noted; but the bias isn't the point of this answer, it is about controlling the sequence of random numbers generated. For all we know, OP wants the bias.

Comment: I bet they don't though. If I had a dollar for every paper I had read whose results are down to a dodgy random number generator, I'd be very rich indeed.

Comment: @Bathsheba agreed, but like I say, that's not the point of the answer (nor the question).

Comment: Indeed but I like to throw remarks on generator misuse whenever I can, if only to make me poorer.